# Where can I find my combat level on RuneScape: Idle Adventures?

Tags: runescape-idle-adventures

**Note, this is not for RuneScape. This is for [RuneScape: Idle Adventures](http://hyperhippo.ca/games/runescape/).

Thorns, Heal, and Swiftness require CB level 25, 50, and 100 respectively for dungeons in RuneScape: Idle Adventures. I have looked all over the UI but can't seem to find where my combat level is?

Is my combat level the sum of my combat skill levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your total combat skill levels

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't say, you will need a calculator and add all your combat levels manually until it's added in an update. After 300 there are no new buffs anyway afaik.